# How to stop an array method if the condition must only satisfied once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, break

I have given a simple task to iterate through an array `arr` and remove each element starting from the first element (the 0 index) until the function `func` returns `true` when the iterated element is passed through it.

Then return the rest of the array "once" the condition is satisfied, otherwise, `arr` should be returned as an empty array. So `dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1]` should return `[1, 0, 1]`.

To answer my question, I use the array filter method but the code below will return `[1, 1]`. Is it possible to stop an array method in this problem? What should I add to my code to stop it once the condition returns true?

```
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  return arr.filter(func);
}

dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], function(n) {return n === 1;});
```

Comment: Might be more clean if you made the `func` into into own function and used it as an argument in the filter method. As in, `const getOne = (n) => n === 1;` then doing `[0, 1, 0, 1].filter(getOne)` (with some proper, descriptive variable name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `findIndex` instead, to find the index matching the condition, then `.slice` to take only what's after it:

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  const index = arr.findIndex(func);
  return index === -1 ? [] : arr.slice(index);
}

console.log(dropElements([0, 1, 0, 1], n => n === 1));
```